# Understanding Xamarin stack trace

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I had a bunch of errors pop up in the wild yesterday and I am trying to understand more about the stack trace. Specifically does this mean that the error happened in the constructor of `LiveEventPageViewModel`? At first glance, I can't seem to find where I would have an NRE in the constructor at least.

```
Xamarin Exception Stack:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Mobile.ViewModels.LiveEventPageViewModel+<>c__DisplayClass155_2.<.ctor>b__25 () <0x104e59740 + 0x00028> in <78675ea96ed449259a925f705a9483ae#82b92fbd1137ac2cb642d6b195f4e27e>:0
  at Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply () <0x1040e2a70 + 0x00023> in <234f9d1731fd4e1ebf977b0a61b8dd61#82b92fbd1137ac2cb642d6b195f4e27e>:0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.xamarin_UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr,intptr&)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (System.Int32 argc, System.String[] argv, System.IntPtr principalClassName, System.IntPtr delegateClassName) <0x10411b330 + 0x00033> in <234f9d1731fd4e1ebf977b0a61b8dd61#82b92fbd1137ac2cb642d6b195f4e27e>:0
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) <0x10411b400 + 0x0005f> in <234f9d1731fd4e1ebf977b0a61b8dd61#82b92fbd1137ac2cb642d6b195f4e27e>:0
  at redacted.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) <0x103298ad0 + 0x00023> in <3d3c1bdeb22740829833318dcbef716d#82b92fbd1137ac2cb642d6b195f4e27e>:0
```

Here is the constructor for this particular ViewModel. The only thing I could think of is either `app` is null or `app.CurrentUser` but that is checked before I even load this page. The user is logged into the app, and is required to be logged in to even get this deep.

```
      public LiveEventPageViewModel(long evtId, ContentPage page, bool onSiteMode) {
                var app = (Application.Current as App);
                SelectedTab = 1;
                this.OnSiteMode = onSiteMode;
    
                eventService = new EventService();
                LiveEventService = new LiveEventService();
                PollService = new PollService();
    
                this.eventId = evtId;
                this.page = page;
                this.currentUser = app.CurrentUser;
                this.currentUserId = app.CurrentUser.Id;
    
                app.AppResumed += App_AppResumed;
    
                Messages = new ObservableCollection<MessageModel>();
                Xamarin.Forms.BindingBase.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Messages, null, ObservableCollectionCallback);
    
                Questions = new ObservableCollection<QuestionHistoryViewModel>();
                Polls = new ObservableCollection<PollViewModel>();
    
                SendMessageCommand = new Command(async () => { await SendMessage(this.currentUser.FirstName + " " + this.currentUser.LastName, Message); });
                UpVoteQuestionCommand = new Command(async (parameter) => { await UpVote(parameter); });
                VoteOnPollCommand = new Command(async (parameter) => { await VoteOnPoll(parameter); });
                CompleteEventCommand = new Command(async (parameter) => { await CompleteEvent(); });
                TapbackIssuedCommand = new Command(async (parameter) => { await TapbackIssued(parameter); });
                MarkQuestionAnsweredCommand = new Command(async (parameter) => { await MarkQuestionAnswered(parameter); });
                MarkQuestionUnAnsweredCommand = new Command(async (parameter) => { await MarkQuestionUnAnswered(parameter); });
                TogglePollVisibilityCommand = new Command(async (parameter) => { await TogglePollVisibility(parameter); });
    
                hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .WithUrl(Constants.ServerAddress + "liveeventhub", options => {
                        options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(currentUser.AccessToken);                         
                    })
                    .WithAutomaticReconnect(new RetryPolicy()).Build();
    
                hubConnection.Reconnected += HubConnection_Reconnected;
    
                hubConnection.On<long, string, string, long, long>("postChat", (id, name, message, userId, eventId) => {
                    if (eventId != this.eventId) {
                        return;
                    }
    
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                        Messages.Add(new MessageModel() { Id = id, UserId = userId, User = name, Message = message, IsSystemMessage = false, IsOwnMessage = userId == currentUserId });
                        this.MessageReceived.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                    });
    
                });
}
```

Comment: yes, ctor mean in the constructor.

Comment: As a general design pattern, try not to let your constructors get too complicated or dependent on other classes. And obviously they should never be able to fail. If your constructor is growing to be too complex, I recommend moving the logic into a factory pattern. It allows you to fail to create an object, and also makes the stack traces a bit nicer for these situations. Also, in my experience, VS acts oddly when it crashes inside a constructor.

Comment: Where do you call this constructor? Did you put a breakpoint in the constructor and step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: I cant get this crash to happen. Its happening in the wild, but I can't recreate it.